# Adding a USR-ES1 W5500 chip for Raspberry 3 A+

Tags: ethernet, spi

I am currently thinking about a project in which space should be kept to a minimum.

Now I am using the A+ model because it is smaller however I do need an ethernet port. So what I am planning to do is to add ethernet port using GPIO pins as I saw people do that using enc28J60, However the enc28J60 is quite large so I found the W5500.

Now my question is will it work if I connect and configure it like I would do for enc28J60 or is there deference between the two?

Another question is will work just as a normal ethernet port or does it missing a protocol or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question***

> will [W5500] work like enc28J60?
>
> a normal ethernet port or missing something?

***Answer***

Sparkfun used to sell Arduino Ethernet shield, but no longer.  I think W5x00 is OK for home use and hobbyists.  It is 802.3 so hobbyists should be more than happy to play with.

[image: w5500]

***References***

[WIZnet W5500 Datasheet via SparkFun](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/W5500_datasheet_v1.0.2_1.pdf)

[SparkFun Arduino W5100 Ethernet Pro Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10536)

Comment: You are welcome.  If you don't insist Ethernet, perhaps consider the very small footprint WiFi guy ESP8266-12/32 boards.